# If two multiprocessing can request input on the terminal, is there a way to pause one of them until the answer is given?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

As can be seen in the code below, two multiprocessing runs together, but both have a moment that can ask for an `input()` in the Terminal, is there any way to pause the other multiprocessing until the answer is given in the Terminal?

File `Code_One` archaic and simple example to speed up the explanation:

```
from time import sleep

def main():
        sleep(1)
        print('run')
        sleep(1)
        print('run')
        sleep(1)
        input('Please, give the number:')
```

File `Code_Two` archaic and simple example to speed up the explanation:

```
from time import sleep

def main():
        sleep(2)
        input('Please, give the number:')
        sleep(1)
        print('run 2')
        sleep(1)
        print('run 2')
        sleep(1)
        print('run 2')
        sleep(1)
        print('run 2')
        sleep(1)
        print('run 2')
```

File `Main_Code`:

```
import Code_One
import Code_Two
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep

def main():
    while True:
        pression = multiprocessing.Process(target=Code_One.main)
        xgoals = multiprocessing.Process(target=Code_Two.main)
        pression.start()
        xgoals.start()
        pression.join()
        xgoals.join()
        print('Done')
        sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How should I proceed in this situation?

In this example, as it doesn't pause the other multi, whenever it asks for an input this error happens:

```
input('Please, give the number:')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this is possible. To do it you will need to use some sort of interprocess communication (IPC) mechanism to allow the two processes to coordinate. `time.sleep` is not the best option though, and there are much more efficient ways of tackling it that are specifically made just for this problem.

Probably the most efficient way is to use a [`multiprocessing.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects), like this:

```
import multiprocessing
import sys
import os

def Code_One(event, fno):
    proc_name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print(f'running {proc_name}')
    sys.stdin = os.fdopen(fno)
    val = input('give proc 1 input: ')
    print(f'proc 1 got input: {val}')
    event.set()


def Code_Two(event, fno):
    proc_name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print(f'running {proc_name} and waiting...')
    event.wait()
    sys.stdin = os.fdopen(fno)
    val = input('give proc 2 input: ')
    print(f'proc 2 got input {val}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    event = multiprocessing.Event()
    pression = multiprocessing.Process(name='code_one', target=Code_One, args=(event, sys.stdin.fileno()))
    xgoals = multiprocessing.Process(name='code_two', target=Code_Two, args=(event, sys.stdin.fileno()))
    xgoals.start()
    pression.start()
    xgoals.join()
    pression.join()
```

This creates the `event` object, and the two subprocesses. Event objects have an internal flag that starts out `False`, and can then be toggled `True` by any process calling `event.set()`. If a process calls `event.wait()` while the flag is `False`, that process will block until another process calls `event.set()`.

The `event` is created in the parent process, and passed to each subprocess as an argument. `Code_Two` begins and calls `event.wait()`, which blocks until the internal flag in the `event` is set to `True`. `Code_One` executes immediately and then calls `event.set()`, which sets `event`'s internal flag to `True`, and allows `Code_Two` to proceed. At that point both processes have returned and called `join`, and the program ends.

This is a little hacky because it is also passing the `stdin` file number from the parent to the child processes. That is necessary because when subprocesses are forked, those file descriptors are closed, so for a child process to read `stdin` using `input` it first needs to open the correct input stream (that is what `sys.stdin = os.fdopen(fno)` is doing). It won't work to just send `sys.stdin` to the child as another argument, because of the mechanics that Python uses to set up the environment for forked processes (`sys.stdin` is a IO wrapper object and is not pickleable).

Comment: Hi @Z4-tier , thanks in advance for your time, I updated the question to give a slightly more realistic view of the case, I put an example of very simple use just to deliver the error. These days I tried to understand the use of your indication, but honestly I was not successful in the attempts, it asks for an input even before the codes are running

Comment: @BrondbyIF the way it was originally written (using `Condition`) actually introduced a race condition that would cause the program to behave unpredictably. I updated this answer to use `multiprocessing.event` instead, which gets rid of that problem.